# Why am I not able to get this code using Linq in my asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code to get all my baobjectCode from database.

```
    var maxCode = variables.Where(w => w.code.StartsWith(prefix) && w.code.Length == length)
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.code).Select(s => s.code).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am gettting build error in this maxcode query.

> Error  8   'string' does not contain a definition for 'code' and no extension method 'code' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Can anybody help me out why I am getting this error? Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `BaObject.BaObjectCode` list in your first statement, so `variables` is type of string

```
.Select(w => w.BaObjectCode).ToList();
```

you should do

```
 var maxCode = variables.Where(w => w.StartsWith(prefix) && w.Length == length)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o).FirstOrDefault();
```

in your last statement. Select is not needed at all, you can remove it

Comment: Thanks Archil, how do I need to do with orderby desc? and select? thanks

Comment: See my answer for the OrderByDescending part and the using FirstOrDefault properly on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
.OrderByDescending()
```

before .ToList() on first line then replace the last line with:

```
var maxCode = variables.FirstOrDefault(w => w.StartsWith(prefix) && w.Length == length);
```

That should make it work.